# How to dump mysql database into specific folder in linux using bash script ?

Tags: mysql, directory, dump

I want to dump my database tables into a specific folder repeatedly in a file specified by real time date and time of dumping.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 1. Write this script inside any file for e.g. Sky [file extension doesn't matter] and make this file as executable file


current_date_time="`date "+%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S"`";
cd /home/akashgudadhe/FunZone/
mysqldump -u [user_name] -p[password] [dbname] > `pwd`/"$current_date_time.sql"


2. Run using terminal

./Sky [<----any_of your file name that you preferred above]

It will save [newly_created_file] into specified directory automatically.
```